# Bootstrap Modal without a button prevent default a click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make modal windows for privacy policy in footer, and not with a button as Bootstrap docs show. I want to use text, (a link), but the # is causing the page to load the page with #. I know there is a prev default that will stop the # from working, but I cannot find it on Google, (at least not that's working for me).

```
<div class="row" id="footer">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="#">Galaxy Guitar</a> All Rights Reserved 
        </div><!-- /col-md-3 -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">
          <a href="#" class="md-trigger" onclick="$('#privacyModal').modal('show')">Privacy Policy</a>  
          <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
        </div><!-- /col-md-3 -->

      </div><!-- /footer -->




    </div><!-- container wrapper -->

<!-- Modal Window (Privacy Policy) -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="#privacyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Privacy Policy</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Our privacy policy is.....
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm late to the party. The Jquery of the bootstrap is looking to prevent the default action of the button- or in your case the link.

An alternative would be to use your own jQuery to prevent default (see below).

But it's better to follow the documented way.  Include the correct data-* attribute and use the href as the target:

```html
<a href="#privacyModal" class="md-trigger" data-toggle="modal">Privacy Policy</a>
```

Please note that I corrected your ID attribute for your modal. To reference a modal, you do use the modal's ID attribute,  but that ID normally does not have a # in it. You use the # in the reference side only.

example:

If the modal has *id="myModal"*
Your opening tag -if you are using a button - should have an attribute of *data-target="#myModal"* as the referencing information. Or if you are using a link  *href="#myModal"*

As your modal has *id="#privacyModal"* I would presume you would use:
*data-target="##privacyModal"*

or

*href="##privacyModal"*
but I dont not know this would work - I have never inculded a # sign in my id name.